# Criteria Query - where predicate with user made custom function

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, spring-boot, criteria-api

I have made a function to calculate distance between two coordinates in postgreSQL. I would like to use it in my project, to compare the result of the function with a user-specified max distance.
My function looks like this:

```
create or replace function distance(lat double precision, lng double precision, db_lat double precision, db_lng double precision)
  returns double precision as $dist$ 
  begin 
  return 
  6371 * acos(
      cos(radians(lat)) * cos(radians(db_lat))
      *
      cos(radians(db_lng) - radians(lng))
      +
      sin(radians(lat))
      *
      sin(radians(db_lat))
    );
    
    end;
    $dist$ language plpgsql;
```

It calculates the distance between two coordinates, one is user-given (to set a point in proximity of which they want to find the records), the other (with db_) are from the existing record in a database.
It works when I try it in pgAdmin, but I'm not sure how to implement it in my java project:

```
public static Specification<Rental> inProximity(Double distance, Double lat, Double lng) {
        if (distance == null || lat == null || lng == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return (root, query, cb) ->
                cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(
                            distance,
                            cb.function("distance", Double.class,
                                    cb.literal(lat),
                                    cb.literal(lng), 
                                    root.get("locationLat"),
                                    root.get("locationLng"))
                    );
        }
    }
```

It marks evething in red and the error says: `Cannot resolve method 'greaterThanOrEqualTo(java.lang.Double, javax.persistence.criteria.Expression<T>)'`
Why isn't the return of the funcion marked as a Double so it would compare two doubles?

When I don't wrap my lat and lng with `cb.literal(),` the error says this:

[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that was way easier than I expected...

```
cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(
                            distance,
                            cb.function("distance", Double.class,
                                    cb.literal(lat),
                                    cb.literal(lng), 
                                    root.get("locationLat"),
                                    root.get("locationLng"))
                    );
```

should be

```
cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(
                            cb.function("distance", Double.class,
                                    cb.literal(lat),
                                    cb.literal(lng), 
                                    root.get("locationLat"),
                                    root.get("locationLng")),
                            distance
                    );
```

Somehow I screwed up the order...